# Noise Reduction help - dealing with a fluctuating gain/noise floor

Tags: noise, reduction

Hi,

I have an interview that was recorded in a room with considerable air-con noise. Fortunately it's the kind of noise that's easy to reduce although the trouble I'm having is that throughout the 1hr 30min recording, the gain on the recorder was adjusted a few times. I've taken a good noiseprint and set a good amount of reduction although when the gain goes up, the noise reduction becomes severe. I'm hoping to avoid some kind of automation and I like using the standalone RX2 as opposed to the ProTools plugins. Any advice??

Thanks, Simon

Answer (score 1):

Fix the volume changing first, then reduce noise.

RX2 Advanced has an adaptive noise reduction feature (the one Andy Lewis is talking about), but I don't think it knows how to handle considerable gain changes. It's meant for noise that varies i.e. cannot be captured by a single "noise print".

Without RX2 Advanced, reduce the noise in parts.

Comment: Thanks guys, yeah I've just gone through and applied clip gain to each gain change - what a job! I'm rendering NR now with a relatively even noise floor. I did try the adaptive mode although I think you're right about it being more for changing noise characteristics. 

Thanks for your advice,
Cheers, Simon

Answer (score 0):

What version of RX2 have you got? In the advanced version you can try using the "Adapt to changing noise profiles" which might help with varying gain changes as you seem to have.